# Trying to use and if else statement with a mysql fetch array and boolean value...keeps counting everything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to build an if statement that will find a boolean value inside an array that was built using an inner join and mysqli_fetch_array inside a while loop, if that value is found display a message, if that value is not found it will display another message. The value I am searching for is 1.

It keeps either displaying 1 alert or two alerts stacked on top of each other, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$query6 = "SELECT user_register.lawyer_client 
           FROM `user_register` INNER JOIN `case_relationship` 
           ON user_register.user_id=case_relationship.user_id 
           WHERE case_relationship.case_id = '$thecaseid'";
$addclient = mysqli_query($dbc, $query6);

<?php
while ($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($addclient)) {
if (in_array("2", $row6)) {
?>
  <div class="container add_client_alert alert">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <a href="new_client.php" class="client_alert">
        <div class="" style="text-align:center;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
         we
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
  else {
    ?>
    <div class="container add_client_alert alert">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <a href="new_client.php" class="client_alert">
        <div class="" style="text-align:center;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          Looks Like Your Client Can't Access This, Click Here To Experience True Client Control
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  }
};
?>
```

Comment: This is a _very_ odd condition you implemented. What is it meant to test? This certainly has nothing to do with "test for boolean" as you wrote (whatever that again is supposed to mean...).

Comment: In plain English, is it true you are looking to: Find all users connected to the case, and whether or not each one of those users is a client?

Comment: Correct, if they are a client they have a column ['lawyer_client'] marked with a 1, if they are not a client they have a column ['lawyer_client'] marked with a 0.

Comment: I really just need to see if any of the rows in the mysqli_fetch_array have a 1, I even tried to only select the rows in my dbtable using LIKE with a value of 1, but it didnt work, Im not even sure if I'm approaching this issue correctly